# A number sequence with a specific property

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

The following increasing number sequence follows a specific number property:

1 2 3 8 10 11 12 13 20 21 22 30 31 68 ...

Find the property and the next two numbers

Hint:

> Use squaring!

Hint 2:

> hex2dec

Comment: Well, to start, it seems to be rot13(vagrtref, naq vapernfvat).

Comment: I hope someone post the old gag of a polynomial interpolating these values.

Comment: @msh210 Well spotted! It also seems to be vig("key", "xyklipc afsgf iss mel mvckxc lc ynhgxk mdlcb rswfcbw rykcdlcb")

Comment: The point of my previous comment was this: The question doesn't _say_ it's an increasing sequence of integers. So it's possible that that's part of the answer. For example, suppose we were asked "The sequence 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,... follows a certain property. Find the property and the next two numbers". Then the answer is "The sequence follows the property that each element after the first 2 is sum of the preceding 2. The next two numbers are 13 & 21". But suppose we were asked "The sequence 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,... follows a certain property. Find the property and the next two numbers". [continued]

Comment: [continued] _Then_ the answer is "The sequence is the set of primes, arranged in increasing order". You'd need to specify it's increasing -- and, more to the point, the question is a bad one, because the answer, "primes, increasing", has two properties that really have nothing to do with one another. It's like asking a sequence whose answer is "primes, that have an odd number of letters in their name" -- why is that interesting? why would any solver think of that? The answer should be cohesive and sensible. In the 2,3,5,7,11 case, a better question would be [continued]

Comment: [continued] "Here's a __set__ of numbers, which I've written the first few of in increasing order. Identify the property defining the set, and identify the next two". _Then_ the answer would be "It's the set of primes". So I'm not sure what's going on in our present question. Is it a good question like my Fibonacci one above, or is it a question with a multipart answer whose parts have nothing to do with one another: (2 or more of) "increasing", "integer", and [something else]? I hope it's the former (but will find out when I find or see the answer).

Comment: @msh210: thanks for your clarification. What you said at the end for the prime numbers is what I intended to ask. I added 'increasing' to the question, hopefully it helps and makes it more obvious.

Comment: Is that 68 correct

Comment: It seems like it should be 32

Comment: 68 is correct and the sequence is increasing, hence next two numbers are greater than 68, so 32 is wrong.

Comment: No I was talking about the number 68 and not the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They appear to be:

> integers whose squares that, when read as a hexadecimal and converted into decimal, result in another square of an integer.  That's a bit clunky, so by way of example, 8 is in this sequence because:
>
> 8^2 = 64 => 64(hex) = 100(dec) => 100 = 10^2.
>
> Whereas 9 is not in the sequence because
>
> 9^2 = 81 => 81(hex) = 129(dec) => 129 is not the square of an integer.

Following this rule, the next two numbers would be:

> 80 and 100

because

> 80^2 = 6400 => 6400(hex) = 25600(dec) => 25600 = 160^2
>
> 100^2 = 10000 => 10000(hex) = 65536(dec) => 65536 = 256^2

Comment: Congrats, you got it!